# Alternative for AngularJS's $route.reload() in Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I would like to be able to fully reload by Angular2 app because something has changed in the data. I could do that in AngularJS through `$route.reload()` (or even `$state.go($state.current.name, $state.params, {reload: true})`), but I can't find an equivalent now.

I know there's `Router.renavigate()`, but that doesn't seem to do much. Is it supposed to do what I'm asking for? Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured this out. `router.renavigate()` will throw away the Component and rebuild it if the Component implements `CanReuse` (from 'angular/router') and returns false from the `canReuse()` method it overrides.

This works for me as of alpha 42.

Comment: There seems to be no router.renavigate() present in the final release